# Multiple types and iteraction over MyBatis parameterClass

Tags: dao, mybatis

I need a query in a MyBatis dao xml file which will receive two parameters: a String object and a list of Strings. It should look something like this:

```
  <select id="findMinTime" parameterClass="????" resultClass="java.lang.Integer">
      select min(time) from table_$first_parameter$ where name in <iterate over second_parameter>
  </select>
```

Any ideas on how to format this query and how to specify these two different parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass two parameters in this way. You should create new class, for example `MyParam` with these two fields:

```
public class MyClass {
  private String param1;
  private List<String> param2;

  // getters and setters
}
```

and use that class in your query. Access those fields like any other fields by name in your query.